# Is question-linking a part of a privilege? Which one? Or is that done through some other mechanism?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, exact-duplicates, hyperlinks

I'm to the point where I don't think I can bring myself to answer `pkgutil --expand-full` again.

Like, ever again. I don't wanna be known for milking this one flag I dug up years ago.

But somehow, like, every time I come to this site,
I see the exact same question. Here's a couple from today:

[How can I open a .pkg file manually?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15658/how-can-i-open-a-pkg-file-manually)
[Foolproof way of extracting .pkg files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34957/foolproof-way-of-extracting-pkg-files)

These turn up in *my own searches* (I was looking into using BOMs in the process of extracting files from disk images without ever mounting them).

And there's still no ready indication/pointer the other pretty much identical questions where that answer has drifted up to the top. So it makes me a little sad. I mean I'm aware some of them are old, but they still turn up pretty quite prominently. And I'm still a ways away from being able to close things dupes, and I'm not sure about that approact anyway... I just wanna be able to prominently link to... ok. Interesting. (Smacks forehead.) I guess I haven't answered that one all that all often here. They're all over at SO. Not sure if that makes me feel better or worse. (Do cross-site linked questions exist?) [How to extract contents from 'Payload' file in a apple macOS update package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166805/how-to-extract-contents-from-payload-file-in-a-apple-macos-update-package/50835954#50835954)

Well I need to get some sleep, after that I'm sure I'll feel a bit better about it (or forget about it for another two months). But it makes me more sad than anything. Maybe I should just answer a bunch of ancient questions for posterity. I mean, it is the *right* answer.

Anyway, thoughts?

(Oh yeah, and I had a question. The "linked questions" in the sidebar is the domain of ...whom?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The "linked questions" in the sidebar is the domain of ...whom?

From the [[linked-questions] tag excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions):

> The "Linked Questions" sidebar is a user-generated list of related questions shown when viewing a question. Its content comes from questions that users have linked in the question, their answers, or in comments, or questions which have been closed as a duplicate of the current question.

So *everybody* can contribute to that list.

---

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve with the rest of your post. If you see the umpteenth duplicate question about opening a package, just flag it as a duplicate. If it's not really a duplicate, one of the questions might be able to be turned into a [canonical question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-questions).

Comment: Ah. It's an algorithm. For some reason I always thought it was curated. The canonical question thing is something I'll look into. Thanks.

Comment: @GeoffNixon I don't think it's an _algorithm_, so much as just a convenient accumulation of all the links people have posted in answers, comments, etc. No decision process involved anywhere.